# 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider'

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

I am running my website on IIS. The default page shows this message:

> Server Error in '/Enterprise/EnterpriseASP' Application.
>   Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider'
>   to type
>   'EnterpriseASPClient.Core.EnterpriseMembershipProvider'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to
>   cast object of type
>   'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider'
>   to type
>   'EnterpriseASPClient.Core.EnterpriseMembershipProvider'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 78:  Line 79:         Protected
>   Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As
>   System.EventArgs) Line 80:
>   MyBase.OnLoad(e) Line 81:
>   Helper.WireViews(Me) Line 82:
>   End Sub
>
> Source File:
>   C:\Enterprise\EnterpriseASPClient\Core\PageBase.vb
>   Line: 80
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast
>   object of type
>   'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider'
>   to type
>   'EnterpriseASPClient.Core.EnterpriseMembershipProvider'.]
>   Login.Page_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +607
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +99
>   EnterpriseASPClient.Core.PageBase.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) in
>   C:\Enterprise\EnterpriseASPClient\Core\PageBase.vb:80
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   +47    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1436

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're incorrectly trying to cast (either explicitly or implicitly) an object of type `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider` to type `EnterpriseASPClient.Core.EnterpriseMembershipProvider`.

Please provide a little more detail about what's actually going on in your program.

I'm guessing your overridden `OnLoad()` function - or actually the `Helper.WireViews()` method it calls - is doing something inadvisable with casting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom AccountMembershipProvider, remember you need to set this in your web config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AccountMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AccountMembershipProvider" type="Foo.Bar.AccountMembershipProvider"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```